# Convert Observable<any> to Observable<customtype> in angular2, typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

How can we convert between types in typescript? like Observable `<any>` to Observable`<array of custom_type>`.
Do we need to use map function to map each value in incoming item of list or is there some other typecasting mechanism?

sample code

```
private list: Observable<any>;
this.list = af.database.list('/list/') //af: AngularFire
```

Comment: can't you think of to use `T` like `Observable<T>` which would be generic

Comment: Actually I need to have a custom type

Comment: Could you post some code? What does the Observable really emit? Does it emit instances of Array<CustomType>, or does it emit comething else, that needs to be transformed into an Array<CustomType>?

Comment: in my case observable is a list of objects (from angularfire2) using the query 'af.database.list' which normally can be received as Observable<any>